# How do I add a way to check if someone is Already in clan/or if they are clan owner in Discord - Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, sqlite, discord, discord.js

I am making a Clan Systems on a Discord Bot using Discord.js.

What I am having trouble is I am trying to make a function where it checks if the user is already in a clan or if the clan owner is trying to make another clan when they are already in one. I am currently able to prevent users making another clan if the same name is already existed:

`` if (clans) return message.channel.send(`**NateBot |** **Error Whilst Creating Clan** ❌\n\n*The Clan with the name **\`${name}\`** already exists!*`); ``

But to check if someone is already in the clan trying to make a clan or owner is trying to make a clan if they are already in one.

`` if (!clans) return message.channel.send(`**NateBot |** **You are already in a Clan silly!** ❌\n\n*Possible reasons are because you're either the Owner of this clan or you are a member of the existing clan you joined.*`); ``

Full Code:
createclan.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const db = require(`quick.db`)
const moment = require("moment");

exports.run = async (client, message, args, color) => {

  let name = args.splice(0).join(" ")
       if (!name) return message.channel.send("**NateBot |** You must specify a Clan Name ")
         if (message.author.bot) return message.channel.send(`**NateBot |** **Bots cannot use the Clans System!**`)

  let clanowner = message.author.username
  let clanownerid = message.author.id
  let clanowneravatar = message.author.displayAvatarURL
  let clanownertag = message.author.tag

  //Other
  let names = name
  let date = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')

  let clans = await db.fetch(`customclans_${name}`)

    if (clans) return message.channel.send(`**NateBot |** **Error Whilst Creating Clan** ❌\n\n*The Clan with the name **\`${name}\`** already exists!*`);
 if (!clans) return message.channel.send(`**NateBot |** **You are already in a Clan!** ❌\n\n*Possible reasons are because you're either the Owner of this clan or you are a member of the existing clan you joined.*`);

        db.set(`customclans_${name}.name`, names) // Name of Clan
        db.set(`customclans_${name}.clanowner`, clanowner) // Owner of Clan
        db.set(`customclans_${name}.clanownerid`, clanownerid) // Owner ID of Clan
        db.set(`customclans_${name}.clanownertag`, clanownertag) // Owner ID of Clan
        db.set(`customclans_${name}.clanowneravatar`, clanowneravatar) // Owner Avatar of Clan user.tag
        db.set(`customclans_${name}.date`, date) //Date clan was created

        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(`**Custom Clans**`)
        .setDescription(`**You created a Clan!** ✅\n\n**Tag Name »** ${name}\n*View your clan with **n!claninfo***`)
        .setColor(`#39db69`)
        .setFooter(`Note: Clans are Global across servers.`)

        message.channel.send(embed)

}

exports.conf = {
    aliases: ['setbio'],
    cooldown: "10"
}

exports.help = {
    name: "setinfo",
    description: "Set your info then tell your friends about you",
    usage: "setinfo <text>"
}
```

I've tried these methods but to no avail. Asking here for some help on how to resolve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, using a similar data structure is not possible. When creating a clan, try writing its ID to another table and checking this. As far as I understood from the `quick.db` documentation, it does not allow you to make complex database selections. If you plan to use some complex structure, this database will not be the best choice. Better use Mysql, or mongoose module of MongoDB for discord. Using and tuning database data will be more complicated. Although mongo has a fairly friendly interface This will allow you to do some more complex checks.

Comment: This is the one of the only ways I am able to get the DB to store the data properly, if I just do db.set(`customclans_${name}`, clanowneravatar`) data will be store improperly. Heres an example: https://imgur.com/a/qOyJ5tQ

I am pretty experienced with quick.db. I know how it works and therefore, making a clan system with quick.db is very possible and will work well. All I am having issue with is to make it check if someone is already in the clan trying to make a clan or owner is trying to make a clan if they are already in one.

Comment: https://github.com/NTMNathan/servertagsbot is example and working on Clans based on my ServerTags Bot

Comment: I don't see in the quick.db documentation  that it is possible to use a select for data fields, so this check is not possible in your approach.

Comment: Yeah, well. I could try the id method you explained earlier and see how it goes.

The Name of the clan is kind of like representing the clan id so I could try for example: db.set(`customclans_${clanidnumber}-${name}.clanownerid`, clanownerid)